# Can anyone answer the SQL Question with Sub Queries and CTE?

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I had an interview and the interviewer asked me the question below. I couldn't make it. Can anyone please answer the question in 2 different ways (Sub Queries and With Clause - CTE)?

Q3: What is the maximum number of employees working on one project? Just return that number.

Q4: which department has the highest combined salary across all of its employees? Return the total salary number, the department name and the number of the employees who are in that department.

Tables:

**Employees**
ID  int
First_Name  varchar
Last_Name   varchar
Salary  int
Department_ID   int

**Departments**
id  int
name    varchar

**Projects**
ID  int
Title   varchar
Start_Date  date
End_Date    date
Budget  int

**Employees_Projects**
Project_id  int
Employee_id int

Comment: It should be simple data aggregation query. What have you tried so far? Start with Grouping `GroupBy` and aggregate functions like `Count()`, `Sum()`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no effort has been demonstrated to solve the question themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t see the point for a subquery or a CTE or a subquery, you can just aggregate and sort:

```
select
    d.name dept_name,
    sum(e.salary) payroll,
    count(*) count_of_employees
from departments d
inner join employees e on e.department_id = d.id
group by d.id, d.name
order by sum(e.salary) desc
limit 1
```

The actual syntax for limiting the number of results varies across RDBMS. SQL Server has `TOP 1 [WITH TIES]`.

Comment: Thank you. Is there anyway we could use via subquery without using limit and top clause